# Soul Package is adjusting text diff, underline overfill/ overflow

Tags: compiling, soul

MikTex through StudioTex also on Sharetex soul package 
is adjusting the alignments differently now, its like emails from a High school principal and overfilling in underlined commands.
As in its editing text outside my bracketing " { } "

Comment: Can you post the LaTeX code of a small example that shows the problem, and describe a bit more precisely what's wrong and how you would like it to behave?

Comment: PREAMBLE:
% Title Page
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

The Highlighting command won't compile and the boldface command \textbf{ ex} will overflow .i.e ( text flooding outside bracketing " \textbf { how now brown } cow, text will pass  "}"  and affect "cow" too.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me...

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{layout} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\begin{document}
 \begin{center} The Highlighting command won't compile and the boldface command \textbf{ex} will overflow i.e.\ (text flooding outside bracketing "\hl{\textbf {how now brown}} cow, text will pass "\}" and affect "cow" too.
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Through studiotex and sharetex? I can send a screenshot

Comment: can you send some too because Its overflowing the brackets and hl command isn't working

Comment: Please? Im going to cry this is so weird and Its for my environmental policy thesis

Comment: Send you some what?  I don't know studiotex and have never used sharetex.  If I can't reproduce the problem then I have no hope in finding the source of the problem.